# Refresh value on page after form submit

Tags: php, html

So to simplify this considerably I'm not using my actual code but just trying to convey what I'm trying to do which is with a lot more data. let's say I have an external text file with 1 value, this value is 100. I use

```
$data=file('text.txt');
```

to bring in that value and display it on the page.

```
echo "<p> Amount: $data[0] </p>";
```

I then have a form submit button that when I click it will decrease that value and modify the text file by displaying 99. When I click submit I have a print_r($data) that shows the modified value of 99 stored in the text file but the page still displays 100. The value only updates after I refresh the page altogether and I'd like it to be so the value updates to the when I click submit. I hope this makes sense, I'll try to clarify as best as I can.

Edit:
My form action is just the current page which is index.php

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
```

Comment: If you want a specific answer please post a specific question. To be able to help with updating your file I need to see the relevant code that works with that process in your project.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided to solve your issue, When the page submits you can retrive the data from the txt file again and show the it in the page. If you have a submit button it obviously refreshes the page. So there won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP finishes doing its job once the page is loaded.

In your case, the new value will be displayed on the page ONLY after the page itself is refreshed. There is no way of changing the display without refreshing the page.

If you want to interactively change the value of the displayed text without refreshing the page itself, you will have to use Javascript.

---

...But if the displayed value isn't updated even after you submit (and is only updated after you hit refresh), there is a possibility that you are calling `echo` before you update the text file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can already successfully update the file but cannot re-display that value on the page... once the page refreshes it should re-get the value and put the new value into your field. If you want to do that without refreshing you can do it with AJAX like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
        var newint = <?php echo $data[0]; ?>;
    document.getElementById('newvalue').innerHTML = newint;
}
</script>
<p id='newvalue'></p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```