# How to remove a deleted value after form submit on page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I'm stuck at a problem again.

I have a form where I check some products, after finishing I submit this form to remove some products. My page is redirecting to the same page.

The value is deleted from the database, but not on the page. I have to refresh the page to get this also done on the page and the products are removed.

I thought I could refresh the page but javascript but I'm not save with JS I'll try to refresh page after formsubmit with onformsubmit location.reload()

I thought I found the solution with this cause this is exactly the same problem I have: [Refresh value on page after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300916/refresh-value-on-page-after-form-submit)

My form:

```
  echo "<form method='post' action='../controller/product_view.php' name='removeProduct' id='removeProduct'>";
        echo "<div class='product_navigation_bar'>";
        echo "<span class='product_navigation_bar_title'> Product List </span>";
        echo "<span class='product_navigation_bar_content'> If you want to delete some products Check the checkboxes and submit it with this button: </span>";
        echo "<button class='btn btn-danger remove_button' onclick='reloader();' type='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>";
        
    echo "</div>";
    
    echo "<div class='product_view_wrap'>";
        $n = 0;

        foreach ($getProduct AS $arr)
        {
            echo "<div class='product_block'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='remove_product' name='remove_product[".$n."]' value='".$arr["SKU"]."'>";
            echo "<span>"."SKU: ".$arr["SKU"]."</span>";
            echo "<span>"."Name: ".$arr["NAME"]."</span>";
            echo "<span>"."Price: ".$arr["PRICE"]." €"."</span>";
            $type = $arr["TYPE"];

            switch($type)
            {
                case $type == "DVD":
                    echo "<span>".$arr["VALUE"]." mb</span>";
                    break;

                case $type == "BOOK":
                    echo "<span>".$arr["VALUE"]." Kg</span>";
                    break;

                case $type == "FURNITURE":
                    $dimension = explode(";", $arr["VALUE"]);
                    echo "<span>".$dimension[0]."cm x ".$dimension[1]."cm x ".$dimension[2]."cm </span>";
            }

            echo "</div>";
            $n++;
        }

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
```

My function:

```
public function removeProduct()
    {
        $db = $this->getDb();
        $array =  [$_POST['remove_product']];
        $value = '';

        foreach ($array AS $arr => $key){
            $result = $key;
        }

        if($result > 0)
        {
            $value = implode(",",$result);
        }

        try {
            $query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE SKU IN ({$value})";
            $result = $db->exec($query);
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Sorry something went wrong ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

So I'll try to refresh the page after click on submit button I call the js function:

```
function reloader() {
    if(!alert('The products will be deleted.')){window.location.reload();}
}
```

but it's not working. My product is deleted from db. But it wont refresh the page to show the new list without the deleted products .

Comment: Your usage of prepare statement are dangerous don't use prepare query like that. It's not an answer for your problem but it's important.

Comment: thank you for the help, i will read about it how to do this better. thank you

Comment: You can reload the page or make a javascript function to remove the element in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is incomplete, but the problem surely is you are generating `$getProduct` before running `removeProduct()` function.

Remember PHP is server side, meaning it's executed in the server, so once you post the form, first you have to delete the products and second you have to populate `$getProduct` with the products remaining in the table.

Another option is to use a Javascript/Ajax combination for deleting and refreshing the page.

Comment: thank you , this helped me out. i change the order in my view and call the removeProduct() before the getProduct

it was so simple and i didn't see it. thank you Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE SKU IN ({$value})";
$result = $db->exec($query);

return $result;

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
</script>';
```